# All database settings are set to 'A'

Tags: 7, database

I'm encountering a very weird problem where my database settings look like this in `database.inc:openConnection()`

```
array(1) {
  ["default"]=>
  array(6) {
    ["driver"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["database"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["username"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["password"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["host"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["port"]=>
    string(1) "A"
  }
}
```

It's after I moved the site to a new host with Ubuntu 14.04, so PHP and MySQL are now on a different version.

Another related strange thing is that `drush sql-connect` is not returning anything.

The result of `global $databases; var_dump($databases);` looks normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me. I copied some lines from D6 settings.php. After adding an extra `['default']` here: `$databases['default']['default'] = array(...` things are working fine again.

---

*Note 1: Probably good to not delete this question as someone else might run into something similar at some point.*

*Note 2: Will be nice if Drupal 8+ will have a more informative way of error reporting.*